# Identifying the device the HTTP request comes from

Tags: http, http-headers

I am writing an application which uses the code in such a way that I should be able to use the same code base for a laptop or a large desktop or a tablet or a phone. I understand that the CSS files will be server different to the different devices and of course only the presentation tier will be different and that too mostly for the CSS part. Now is there some way to identify what kind of device originated a request? Is there a HTTP request header information I can use?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a Transport Protocol and is independent of the sender and receiver.  Thus, their is no `header` that will tell you the device type of sender. See [HTTP Headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more details.

Yes, your CSS should be different based on the "device type".  Instead of returning different CSS files base on a mythical device type, one CSS file is used with various [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Take a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) as a starter point.

> Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.